# complex query... how to join many classes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following associations:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_lines
  has_many :beverages, through: :sale_lines
end

class SaleLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
  belongs_to :beverage
end

class Beverage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_lines
  has_many :sales, through: :sale_lines

  has_many :recipes
  has_many :products, through: :recipes
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beverage
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :beverages, through: :recipes
end
```

[image: class diagram]

I wan't to see the quantity of products sold by each venue, so basically I have to multiply the `recipe.quantity` by the `sale_line.quantity` of an specific product.

I would like to call `@venue.calc_sales(product)` to get the quantity sold of `product`.

Inside the class `Venue` I am trying to calculating it by:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
  def calc_sales(product)
    sales.joins(:sale_lines, :beverages, :recipes).where('recipes.product_id = ?', product.id).sum('sale_lines.quantity * recipe.quantity')
    end
  end
```

However, I can't access the `recipes` in that way.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: Try using `sales.joins(:sales => { :beverages => :recipes })`

Comment: @MrYoshiji `sales.joins(:sale_lines => { :beverage => :recipes })` did the trick. I don't really understand the rules for pluralization, but it is working in that way. Just put your comment as answer and I will accept it ;) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the joins, you have to use a Hash to join a already-joined table. It's hard to explain, but here are some examples:

- `Venue.joins(:sales, :beverages)` : This implies that the relations `:sales` and `:beverages` are declared on the Venue model.
- `Venue.joins(:sales => :beverages)` : This implies that the relation `:sales` exists on the Venue model, and the relation `:beverages` exists on the Sale model.

---

Consider this:

```
Venue
  has_one :sale
```

- `Venue.joins(:sales)` : This **would not** work, you have to use the exact same name as the relation between the Venue model & Sale model.
- `Venue.joins(:sale)` : This would work because you used the same name of the relation.

**Attention:** You have to use the pluralized name in the where clause:

```
Venue.joins(:sale).where(:sales => { :id => sale.id })
                ^^           ^^ # See the plural
```

---

**In your case**, you can do something like this:

```
sales.joins(:sale_lines => { :beverage => :recipes })
     .where(:recipes => { :product_id => product.id })
     .sum('sale_lines.quantity * recipes.quantity')
```